# how to count the number of rows of a query inside a while loop?

Tags: php, database, count, while-loop

i have the following php code

```
$thread_pick=mysqli_query($db,'SELECT * FROM u_mess WHERE participant_1="'.$display_name.'" OR participant_2="'.$display_name.'" ') or trigger_error(mysqli_error());
if(mysqli_num_rows($thread_pick) >= 1 )
{
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($thread_pick))
  {
    $thread_pick_sub = mysqli_query($db,'SELECT * FROM u_mess_thread WHERE (thread_id="'.$row['thread_id'].'" AND mess_to="'.$display_name.'" )')or trigger_error(mysqli_error());
    echo mysqli_num_rows($thread_pick_sub).'dsddsds';
    $mess_num_count = mysqli_num_rows($thread_pick_sub);
  }
}
```

my problem:the table has two users user 1 has sent 3 messages and user 2 has sent 2 messages now the expected value  inside variable `$mess_num_count` should be 5 but it is showing 2 what do i do  to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's only counting the messages from `user 2` so it's `2`!

To get `5` you have to use the operator `+=` like this:

```
$mess_num_count += mysqli_num_rows($thread_pick_sub);
```

The code should then look like this:

```
$thread_pick=mysqli_query($db,'SELECT * FROM u_mess WHERE participant_1="'.$display_name.'" OR participant_2="'.$display_name.'" ') or trigger_error(mysqli_error());
$mess_num_count = 0;
if(mysqli_num_rows($thread_pick) >= 1 )
{
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($thread_pick))
  {
    $thread_pick_sub = mysqli_query($db,'SELECT * FROM u_mess_thread WHERE (thread_id="'.$row['thread_id'].'" AND mess_to="'.$display_name.'" )')or trigger_error(mysqli_error());
    echo mysqli_num_rows($thread_pick_sub).'dsddsds';
    $mess_num_count += mysqli_num_rows($thread_pick_sub);
  }
}
```

Comment: @user3594202 okay :D nice (in the last 6 min of the day for me it's 23:54) Also you can accept and upvote answers how helped you, so that other people with the same problem finde the answer faster!